# PHP echo HTML element with AJAX script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, echo

I am trying to rewrite the [W3C AJAX Livesearch script](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) to echo a `<button>` instead of an `<a>`, which seems to be printing but the inline Javascript isn't responding to the AJAX script. Here is the PHP I've modified.

```
    $hint="<button='type' class='mybutton' name='users' value='" .
    $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "' onclick='showUser(this.value)'>" .
    $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</button>";
```

I modified the the XML nodes to just contain a title and a value (1-n). The request seems to be working but it looks like the  is not receiving a value. I have a feeling it is something to do with the way I've coded the PHP. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Problem answered, it was a simple syntax error in the markup. I took out my live example link, but refer to the W3C link if you are interested in learning the script. Good stuff!

Comment: Can you describe how it's not working? It looks fine to me; clicking the buttons loads the right details. Also, you should use CSS to change the button appearance. Don't use `onmousedown`, etc to change class names

Comment: @kingkero Looks like a typo. Doesn't look like that in OP's demo code

Comment: @Phil it is not, check the linked site's source code

Comment: @kingkero I have and I don't see any problems

Comment: @Phil You do know it is about the dynamically loaded "button" - type in "Peter" in the input and you'll see ;)

Comment: @kingkero Ah, right you are

Comment: Be very wary of using the `value` property with button elements. IIRC, several versions of IE will use the button's text content instead

Comment: Additionally I'd advise to [stay off w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: I have always avoided W3C, but for once I was very please. They actually have some good AJAX stuff, so I've discovered. But yeah, not pleased with their JS and HTML5 articles.

Comment: @king, that w3fools site is hilarious. It seems W3C doesn't cater to beginners or experts, but more so to intermediate developers; which is odd.

Comment: @phil, the reason I am using JS instead of CSS is because of IE6-7 compatibility.

Comment: @Jim22150 Oh, I'm so very sorry :(

Comment: Ha, @Phil I'm glad you feel my pain. I may look into some  [CSS3PIe] (http://css3pie.com/) solutions once I finish a UI and backend prototype. Right now, I am swapping the XML for JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the HTML you provide in the dynamically loaded content, which looks like this (from inspecting the given link):

```
<button='type' class="mybutton" name="users" value="1" 
    onclick="showUser(this.value)">Peter Griffin </button>
```

`this.value` returns `undefined` as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29XUz/) because this is no valid HTML syntax. You need to provide a proper `button` like the following:

```
<button class="mybutton" name="users" value="1"
    onclick="showUser(this.value)">Peter Griffin </button>
```

Comment: FYI the AJAX response HTML doesn't actually have `</button='type'>`, that's just how your browser is interpreting it

Comment: Wow, I'm embarassed! Simple markup problem. I shouldn't have even posted this question, but it may be helpful for some. @Phil, please read the question again, I was having problems with Livesearch, not the buttons.